# How can i see and/or delete the clipboard contents

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab-a, nook

The only options I get are cut, copy, paste, and select all. I can easily find the clipboard on my Samsung phone using almost all of the suggestions here, but not on my nook tablet A. Can anyone help me discover where this data is to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Clipboard Actions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.halfreal.clipboardactions). It allows to view, delete or even edit the content(s) of the clipboard. Whenever you copy a text, it will be inserted in the Notification bar where you can navigate and choose, view or delete a copied text.

[image: IMG:]

Taping on the Notification bar opens the app, allowing to view all the items copied. You can even edit them.

[image: IMG:]

The app can also copy images and videos, search on Google for the text copied, etc.